# Machine learning methods to identify the recipient of a document?

Tags: natural-language-processing

I need some advice on what AI methods would be suited to the identification of a recipient of a document, where the format of the documents may vary.

Comment: there are different letter format we can input that PDF extract text from that PDF

Comment: High-level, this sounds like it could be a legit task for a learning algorithm, in that there may be great variance in how human to human correspondence is structured.  (Should be an easy, rules-based solution for formal correspondence, but what about informal?  Is this within the scope of the project?)

Comment: I want to train ml or AI for identify the recipient of any business document